# Azure Conditional Access - Exclude MFA for Specific Resource

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-mfa

Is there a way to exclude a conditional access policy from MFA when accessing a specific resource?

In this case it is when accessing a SQL managed instance. Everything else has to apply MFA.

Answer (score 0):

From the conditional access console, you only can exclude "Azure SQL Database"
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it's similar to this, but I had to exclude the service principal which you create under the managed instance when you enable the identity for Windows authentication.

We couldn't go with the managed instance in the end as it was considered a security risk.